# Counting character values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like below.

```
data <- data.frame(Var_1 = c("A","B","C","A","B"))

Var_1
A
B
C
A
B
```

Need to do count like below.

```
Var_1 Count
A     2
B     2
C     1
A     2
B     2
```

Comment: `data.frame(table(data)[data$Var_1])`

Comment: With devel dplyr, `data %>% add_count(Var_1)`. With CRAN dplyr, `data %>% group_by(Var_1) %>% mutate(Count = n())`. With base R, maybe `data$Count <- ave(as.integer(data$Var_1), data$Var_1, FUN = length)`. With data.table, `setDT(data)[, Count := .N, by = Var_1][]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(Var_1 = c("A","B","C","A","B"))

# make a frequency table to determine the "count"
countsDF <- table(df$Var_1)

# use names to match the Var_1 in the countsDF, then assign
# the corresponding count
df$count <- countsDF[match(df$Var_1,  names(countsDF))]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can try using the table and storing it as a dataframe, from this data frame you can access the frequency of your data.

```
    > data <- data.frame(Var_1 = c("A","B","C","A","B"))
    > df <- as.data.frame(table(data))
    > df$data
    [1] A B C
    Levels: A B C
    > df$Freq
    [1] 2 2 1
    > df
      data Freq
    1    A    2
    2    B    2
    3    C    1
```

PS: I am not sure if you mean to repeat the 'levels' of your data as mentioned in your question, but unless it is case specific (which is not mentioned) I would take a repetitive class or level into consideration.